# How to use Youtube's API V3 pagination features?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I just started using Youtube's v3 API and I'm stucked somewhere am supposed to use pagination but do not know how to do that!

I can only go to the next page using `nextpagetoken` as `pagetoken` but I can't get back to the previous page!

```
if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $noPage = $_GET['page'];
    $page = ($noPage-1)*20;
    $pageToken = $_SESSION["nextToken"];
} else {
    $noPage = 1;
    $page = 1;
}
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array('q' => $q, 'maxResults' => $maxResults, 'type' => "video", 'pageToken' => $pageToken,));
if ($noPage > 1) {
    //echo'<a href="?page='.($noPage-1).'"><input type="submit" value="&laquo; Previous Page"/></a> - ';
    echo'<a href="'.$vhome.'search.html?q='.querydecode($q).'&amp;page='.$prev.'"><input type="submit" value="&laquo; Previous Page"/></a> - ';
}
if ($searchResponse['nextPageToken']) {
    //echo '<a href="?page='.($noPage+1).'"><input type="submit" value="Next Page &raquo;"/></a>';
    echo '<a href="'.$vhome.'search.html?q='.querydecode($q).'&amp;page='.$next.'"><input type="submit" value="Next Page &raquo;"/></a>';
}
```

How do I get results for both next and prev page?

Answer (score 1):

A search result for page 1 will contain a "nextPageToken' ... if you set that as the 'pageToken' parameter, and leave all other parameters from the query the same, it'll load page 2.

```
// loads the first page of results
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array('q' => $q, 'maxResults' => $maxResults, 'type' => "video"));
// this gets page two of results
$newSearchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array('q' => $q, 'maxResults' => $maxResults, 'type' => "video", 'pageToken' => $searchResponse["nextPageToken"]));
```

Page two will also contain a 'nextPageToken' which you can use to go to page 3, but page 2 also returns a 'prevPageToken'; if you set the 'pageToken' parameter to that value and re-run your request, you'll get the results from page 1 again.

```
// loads the third page of results
$newNewSearchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array('q' => $q, 'maxResults' => $maxResults, 'type' => "video",'pageToken' => $newSearchResponse["nextPageToken"]));
// this goes back to page 1 of results
$oldSearchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array('q' => $q, 'maxResults' => $maxResults, 'type' => "video", 'pageToken' => $newSearchResponse["prevPageToken"]));
```